# how to find the find the following scenario in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have content like this:

```
<sect1>
    <title>Leiblichkeit und Verk&#x00F6;rperung</title>
    <sect2>
        <title>Leiblichkeit und Verk&#x00F6;rperung</title>
        <para>
        .......
        </para>
    </sect2>
    <sect2>
        <title>Leiblichkeit und Verk&#x00F6;rperung</title>
        <para>
        .......
        </para>
    </sect2>
</sect1>
```

I want to match and apply attribute for `sect2`'s `title` if its continues to `sect1` as "below_2_head"

I tried:

```
<xsl:template match="title">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="parent::sect1"><xsl:attribute name="aid:pstyle">1_head</xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="parent::sect2"><xsl:attribute name="aid:pstyle"><xsl:if test="parent::sect2/preceding-sibling::title">below_</xsl:if>2_head</xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|comment()|processing-instruction()|text()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I want the output as:

```
<sect1>
    <title aid:pstyle="1_head">Leiblichkeit und Verk&#x00F6;rperung</title>
    <sect2>
        <title aid:pstyle="below_2_head">Leiblichkeit und Verk&#x00F6;rperung</title>
        <para>
        .......
        </para>
    </sect2>
    <sect2>
        <title aid:pstyle="2_head">Leiblichkeit und Verk&#x00F6;rperung</title>
        <para>
        .......
        </para>
    </sect2>
</sect1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is here:

```
<xsl:if test="parent::sect2/preceding-sibling::title">
```

This will be true for *both* of the `sect2` elements in your example document as they both have *some* preceding sibling element that is a `title`.  What you actually need to check is just the *immediately* preceding sibling element, to see whether that element is a title or not:

```
<xsl:if test="parent::sect2/preceding-sibling::*[1][self::title]">
```